# \chapter command and skak package

Tags: chapters, chess, skak

Is there a way to write a chapter title using chess figurines?
I'm using the `skak` package and

```
\chapter{\mainline{1.e4 e6 2.d4 b6}}
```

doesn't work. Same error using the `\variation` command.

I'll post the exact error output when I'll be back home if needed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using a parsing command like `\mainline` in an moving argument is very problematic. I would suggest to do the parsing outside with `\hidemoves` and to print the moves with `xskak`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xskak}

\begin{document}
\newchessgame[id=title]
\hidemoves{1.e4 e6 2.d4 b6}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{\protect\printchessgame[id=title]}


\printchessgame[id=title]
\chessboard[id=title]


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the contents of a `\chapter` (or any/most sectional headings) are moving/fragile (they end up in the ToC, for example), care should be taken. However, you can *box* the content and then insert the box as part of your chapter heading. This is also not fool-proof, but at least provides a means to obtain the desired output in the chapter heading:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{skak}% http://ctan.org/pkg/skak
\newsavebox{\mybox}
\begin{document}
\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}\huge\newgame\longmoves\longmoves\mainline{1.e4 c5 2.Nf3 Nc6}\end{lrbox}
\chapter{\usebox{\mybox}}
\end{document}
```

Since the contents of `\mybox` is fixed in terms of its typesetting, I've used `\huge` which is similar to that of the regular `\chapter` title (in [`book.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/book.cls)).

---

Another (better) alternative would be to use the Chess Font Selection Scheme [`chessfss`](http://ctan.org/pkg/chessfss) to construct your chapter/symbol headings:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{chessfss}% http://ctan.org/pkg/chessfss
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chess: \textsymking, \textsymqueen, \textsymrook, \textsymbishop, \textsymknight, \textsympawn}
\end{document}
```

This works well with inserting the content in the ToC without problem. See the [`chessfss` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/chessfss/chessfss.pdf) for more details on how to modify the symbol masks and colours.

Comment: thank you. I'll try chessff and if it works for me (as I hope) and I will not receive any solution using skak I'll vote your answer as the best one ;)

Comment: @MementoMori: What is it that you want exactly? A chess board, some pieces/symbols, or create a board via moves? You could capture the content of `\mainline` in a box and then use that as your chapter title. That is another alternative.

Comment: capturing the output of \mainline (or \variation) and reusing it would be a great solution!

Comment: @MementoMori: I've updated my answer to reflect a box-capturing technique. It depends highly on your usage though.

Comment: thank you for sharing your knowledge but I've tried the solution offered by Ulrike and it seems a little easier to use. Anyway I'm sure your answer will save me time and headhaches in the future. Thank you again.