# import data chess dat for xskak with \input command

Tags: xskak

Is there a way to import chess data from a file?
The content of the file can be restricted to the moves only.

It is clear to me that

```
\hidemoves{\input{datafile}}
```

can not work.
However, is it possible to expand `\input{datafile}` first and feed the result to `\hidemoves` afterwards?

Comment: You haven't provided a test file so untested but probably `\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\hidemoves\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\csname @@input\endcsname datafile}` will work

Comment: Depends on the content of the file. If it contains only moves of one game it should be possible, but if you have a pgn file with various game you need some script to preprocess the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `readarray` package to place the file contents into a `\def` named `\myhidemoves`.  Then one only needs to expand `\myhidemoves` once before passing it to `\hidemoves`.

EDITED to change `#` catcode for `\readdef`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xskak,filecontents,readarray}
\begin{filecontents*}{datafile}
1.e4 e6 2.d4 b6#
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\newchessgame[id=title]
\catcode`#=12 %
\readdef{datafile}{\myhidemoves}
\catcode`#=6 %
\expandafter\hidemoves\expandafter{\myhidemoves}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{\protect\printchessgame[id=title]}

\printchessgame[id=title]
\chessboard[id=title]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: copied MWE from [\chapter command and skak package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66718/chapter-command-and-skak-package/66755#66755).

Comment: This won't work generally, chess changes the catcode of #  (the mate symbol).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I believe you, of course, but don't fully grok what you are saying.  Is there a simple breaking example for `datafile` you could type in? (I am not a `skak` user)

Comment: Try `\newchessgame\mainline{1.e4 e6 2.d4 b6#}` and in comparision `1.e4 e6 2.d4 b6#` in your datafile.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It would seem that simply changing the `#` catcode for the `\readdef` is sufficient to remedy the issue.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you, that is exactly what I needed.